# Create an php array for sent to SOAP service

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

I have hml which works fine in SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"
                  xmlns:wssc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WSSC.V4.DMS.EKV.WssDocsService">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:CreateDocument>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:parameters>
                <!--Optional:-->

                <!--Optional:-->
                <wssc:DocType>01</wssc:DocType>
                <!--Optional:-->

                <!--Optional:-->

                <!--Optional:-->
                <wssc:FieldValues>
                    <wssc:BaseDocumentField xsi:type="wssc:DocumentField"
                                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <wssc:Name>value1</wssc:Name>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <wssc:Value>email@email.email</wssc:Value>
                    </wssc:BaseDocumentField>
                    <wssc:BaseDocumentField xsi:type="wssc:DocumentField"
                                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <wssc:Name>content</wssc:Name>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <wssc:Value>just text</wssc:Value>
                    </wssc:BaseDocumentField>
                    <wssc:BaseDocumentField xsi:type="wssc:DocumentField"
                                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <wssc:Name>name</wssc:Name>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <wssc:Value>number</wssc:Value>
                    </wssc:BaseDocumentField>
                </wssc:FieldValues>
                <wssc:UserMail>email@email.email</wssc:UserMail>
            </tem:parameters>
        </tem:CreateDocument>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to create an array to repeat its structure.
Now I have such an array, but it does not work to the full:

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'DocType' => '01',
         'UserMail' => 'email@email.email',
        'FieldValues' => array(

            'BaseDocumentField' => array(
                    'name' => 'something',
                    'value' => 'something',
                ),

                'BaseDocumentField' => array(
                    'name' => 'something',
                    'value' => 'something',
                ),

            ),
    )
);

$client = new SoapClient("http://servicename?wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0, "login" => $login, "password" => $password));
$result = $client->CreateDocument($params);
try {
        $request = $client->CreateDocument($params);
        $last_request = $client->__getLastRequest();
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        $last_request = $client->__getLastRequest();
    }
var_dump($last_request);


?>
```

The function **__getLastRequest** produces the following result:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WSSC.V4.DMS.EKV.WssDocsService"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:CreateDocument>
            <ns2:parameters>
                <ns1:DocType>01</ns1:DocType>
                <ns1:FieldValues>
                   <ns1:BaseDocumentField/>
                </ns1:FieldValues>
                <ns1:UserMail>email@email.email</ns1:UserMail>
            </ns2:parameters>
        </ns2:CreateDocument>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I do not understand how to properly construct an array so that the  section is displayed correctly.
how can I do it?

Comment: You should write the keys 'name' and 'value' in your array with uppercase first letters, exactly as described in the wsdl. Maybe this should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a complex WSDL, you should definitively use a WSDL to php generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project. It'll generate all the classes required to construct the request then to receive the response. Using a good IDE such as Eclipse or PhpStorm, you'll have the full auto-completion wich will ease you the request construction without having to wonder how to do it.